# Custom batch file creation for building code generated from Simulink Models

Tags: matlab, simulink

How can I create a custom batch file for my code generated from Simulink model ?

I can see, if I edit and change my template make file from Configuration Parameter Dialog box, I can get the desired make file.

[image]

But I want a custom ***.bat*** file too, that calls this make file along with other commands.

I have some environment variable to set and run couple of scripts in .bat file, before compilation begins. Based on these outputs from script the code is to be compiled and linked.

<sup>***Using Matlab Version: 2012b***</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a STF_wrap_make_cmd_hook that generates your desired *modelname*.bat file as shown in the example code
[here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/target-development-mechanics.html#f46522) (mathworks login necessary).

You will probably also need to write your own make_*yourtarget*.m file and edit the make command field shown in your screenshot to use that one instead of make_rtw.

Other hooks into the build process are described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/customizing-the-target-build-process-with-the-stf-make-rtw-hook-file.html), perhaps the 'before_make' will also be useful.

Comment: Thanks @pmb, but I'm not able to view the individual pages. I do have a mathworks account but it says it needs a licensed user. _"Access to documentation for certain products requires your MathWorks Account to be associated with a license."_ It would be great if you could share the contents

Comment: I assume you have Simulink Coder/Embedded Coder license, so you should be able to see the documentation in the help browser in MATLAB.
Try this in the command window: web([docroot '/toolbox/rtw/ug/bse3caa-1.html#f42994']) or search for "STF_wrap_make_cmd_hook Mechanism"

Comment: Or maybe this command, depends on your version: web(fullfile(docroot, 'rtw/ug/target-development-mechanics.html?searchHighlight=STF_wrap_make_cmd_hook+Mechanism'))

Comment: Thanks I used the help page from installed matlab as you told.
Also a similar issue [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102936)